# How to define string type in getOrInsertFunction() llvm?

Tags: clang, llvm, instrumentation

I'm new to llvm and was trying to do instrument. But I found LLVM API only has primitive types, like: getInt32Ty(Ctx).. What i want to do use getOrInsertFunction(),the function argument type is string type.As is known, when argument type is int, we can do it like is :

```
 LLVMContext &Ctx = F.getContext();
  Constant *logFunc = F.getParent()->getOrInsertFunction(
    "logop", Type::getVoidTy(Ctx), Type::getInt32Ty(Ctx), NULL );
```

`Type::getInt32Ty(Ctx)` is the function argument type (int), what i want to do is:

```
getOrInsertFunction(
    "logop", Type::getVoidTy(Ctx), string type, NULL);
```

The string type i don't know how to define it .In short, could you please tell me how to define it, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

LLVM IR does not define any special string or char types.

Usually either `[N x i8]` or `i8*` are used, but it's really up to you - for example, Java-style strings will probably be a struct with some `i32` for string length and an `i16*` for the UTF-16 code points.

LLVM IR does have a "string literal" which is typed as an `i8` array - for example `c"hello world\0A\00"` is `[13 x i8]`. But that doesn't dictate what string form you should be using.

Keep in mind that if your function is supposed to interop with something, e.g. a hosting C++ application, then you need to use the same string type - in that case whatever `std::string` is compiling to. You can use Clang or [this online demo](http://ellcc.org/demo/index.cgi) to check what that type is.